# Zurb Foundation 5 Dynamic Resize of Top-bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

Currently trying to dynamically resize the topbar according to scrolled height, so that I can achieve something to the effect of: [resize menu bar](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-create-a-resizing-menu-bar/)

However when I try to dynamically allocate the height the elements within do not adjust to the correct height and a total mess is created.  Is there a way to easily dynamically allocate height of the foundation top-bar-nav ?